# When could Mesos tasks be in STAGING state?

Tags: mesos, mesos-chronos

I see mesos tasks in STAGING for more than 2 days. The task is a simple standalone java code execution. I don't seen anything related to STAGING status in my logs. Can someone provide insight on when the job can go into TASK_STAGING.

My Infra has 3 mesos-masters registered with 3 node zookeeper cluster. Chronos is the framework registered with mesos. There are three slaves serving the requests. I see STAGING tasks only on one slave.

Agent Logs:

```
I0119 16:40:25.873868 14221 slave.cpp:3648] Current disk usage 19.32%. Max allowed age: 4.947461624847303days
I0119 16:41:25.875798 14223 slave.cpp:3648] Current disk usage 19.32%. Max allowed age: 4.947459872825081days
I0119 16:42:25.876703 14221 slave.cpp:3648] Current disk usage 19.32%. Max allowed age: 4.947457901800092days
I0119 16:43:25.878134 14221 slave.cpp:3648] Current disk usage 19.32%. Max allowed age: 4.947456149777870days
I0119 16:44:25.879606 14222 slave.cpp:3648] Current disk usage 19.32%. Max allowed age: 4.947453959750105days
I0119 16:45:25.881283 14222 slave.cpp:3648] Current disk usage 19.32%. Max allowed age: 4.947452207727882days
I0119 16:46:25.882928 14225 slave.cpp:3648] Current disk usage 19.32%. Max allowed age: 4.947450236702894days
I0119 16:46:45.423125 14222 slave.cpp:1144] Got assigned task ct:1484866005382:0:TriageReserveEx_Comb_Server-py_1-0_3-4_f5f0b884-d17b-45e0-ae45-88b669360349: for framework 20170112-033024-2583779338-5050-595-0000
I0119 16:46:45.424717 14222 slave.cpp:1254] Launching task ct:1484866005382:0:TriageReserveEx_Comb_Server-py_1-0_3-4_f5f0b884-d17b-45e0-ae45-88b669360349: for framework 20170112-033024-2583779338-5050-595-0000
I0119 16:46:45.443246 14222 slave.cpp:4208] Launching executor ct:1484866005382:0:TriageReserveEx_Comb_Server-py_1-0_3-4_f5f0b884-d17b-45e0-ae45-88b669360349: of framework 20170112-033024-2583779338-5050-595-0000 in work directory '/opt/leantaas/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/20170112-033034-2617333770-5050-2661-S0/frameworks/20170112-033024-2583779338-5050-595-0000/executors/ct:1484866005382:0:TriageReserveEx_Comb_Server-py_1-0_3-4_f5f0b884-d17b-45e0-ae45-88b669360349:/runs/168831c6-dd7d-4492-9fda-e17b868a8cc9'
I0119 16:46:45.445209 14222 slave.cpp:1401] Queuing task 'ct:1484866005382:0:TriageReserveEx_Comb_Server-py_1-0_3-4_f5f0b884-d17b-45e0-ae45-88b669360349:' for executor ct:1484866005382:0:TriageReserveEx_Comb_Server-py_1-0_3-4_f5f0b884-d17b-45e0-ae45-88b669360349: of framework '20170112-033024-2583779338-5050-595-0000
I0119 16:46:45.445219 14223 containerizer.cpp:484] Starting container '168831c6-dd7d-4492-9fda-e17b868a8cc9' for executor 'ct:1484866005382:0:TriageReserveEx_Comb_Server-py_1-0_3-4_f5f0b884-d17b-45e0-ae45-88b669360349:' of framework '20170112-033024-2583779338-5050-595-0000'
I0119 16:47:25.884843 14224 slave.cpp:3648] Current disk usage 19.32%. Max allowed age: 4.947444980636239days
I0119 16:47:45.444521 14222 slave.cpp:3605] Terminating executor ct:1484866005382:0:TriageReserveEx_Comb_Server-py_1-0_3-4_f5f0b884-d17b-45e0-ae45-88b669360349: of framework 20170112-033024-2583779338-5050-595-0000 because it did not register within 1mins
I0119 16:47:45.445416 14226 containerizer.cpp:918] Destroying container '168831c6-dd7d-4492-9fda-e17b868a8cc9'
I0119 16:48:25.887889 14221 slave.cpp:3648] Current disk usage 19.32%. Max allowed age: 4.947443009611250days
I0119 16:49:25.890916 14222 slave.cpp:3648] Current disk usage 19.32%. Max allowed age: 4.947441476591806days
I0119 16:50:25.892485 14226 slave.cpp:3648] Current disk usage 19.32%. Max allowed age: 4.947439505566805days
I0119 16:51:25.894383 14221 slave.cpp:3648] Current disk usage 19.32%. Max allowed age: 4.947437315539039day
```

Here are logs after setting log level to 3

```
I0207 00:51:15.832798 10356 slave.cpp:1144] Got assigned task ct:1486450275786:0:sample_1-0_3-4_d77ed5ab-0d66-43c0-8c2d-3326cbe8aae9: for framework 20170206-001647-2583779338-5050-19797-0001
I0207 00:51:15.833663 10356 slave.cpp:1254] Launching task ct:1486450275786:0:sample_1-0_3-4_d77ed5ab-0d66-43c0-8c2d-3326cbe8aae9: for framework 20170206-001647-2583779338-5050-19797-0001
I0207 00:51:15.852514 10359 clock.cpp:135] Handling timers up to 2017-02-07 06:51:15.852006912+00:00
I0207 00:51:15.852954 10359 clock.cpp:142] Have timeout(s) at 2017-02-07 06:51:15.851180032+00:00
I0207 00:51:15.855445 10357 process.cpp:2160] Resuming reaper(1)@10.88.1.154:5051 at 2017-02-07 06:51:15.854163968+00:00
I0207 00:51:15.855944 10357 clock.cpp:243] Created a timer for reaper(1)@10.88.1.154:5051 in 100ms in the future (2017-02-07 06:51:15.955777024+00:00)
I0207 00:51:15.872143 10356 slave.cpp:4570] Checkpointing ExecutorInfo to '/opt/leantaas/lib/mesos/slave/meta/slaves/20170206-001647-2583779338-5050-19797-S0/frameworks/20170206-001647-2583779338-5050-19797-0001/executors/ct:1486450275786:0:sample_1-0_3-4_d77ed5ab-0d66-43c0-8c2d-3326cbe8aae9:/executor.info'
I0207 00:51:15.873136 10356 slave.cpp:4208] Launching executor ct:1486450275786:0:sample_1-0_3-4_d77ed5ab-0d66-43c0-8c2d-3326cbe8aae9: of framework 20170206-001647-2583779338-5050-19797-0001 in work directory '/opt/leantaas/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/20170206-001647-2583779338-5050-19797-S0/frameworks/20170206-001647-2583779338-5050-19797-0001/executors/ct:1486450275786:0:sample_1-0_3-4_d77ed5ab-0d66-43c0-8c2d-3326cbe8aae9:/runs/1a3fc5c8-3538-43b7-b9d6-dda4bf2e6d49'
I0207 00:51:15.873680 10356 clock.cpp:243] Created a timer for slave(1)@10.88.1.154:5051 in 1mins in the future (2017-02-07 06:52:15.873636864+00:00)
I0207 00:51:15.873905 10354 process.cpp:2160] Resuming files@10.88.1.154:5051 at 2017-02-07 06:51:15.873744896+00:00
I0207 00:51:15.873975 10351 process.cpp:2160] Resuming (3)@10.88.1.154:5051 at 2017-02-07 06:51:15.873810944+00:00
I0207 00:51:15.874140 10356 slave.cpp:4593] Checkpointing TaskInfo to '/opt/leantaas/lib/mesos/slave/meta/slaves/20170206-001647-2583779338-5050-19797-S0/frameworks/20170206-001647-2583779338-5050-19797-0001/executors/ct:1486450275786:0:sample_1-0_3-4_d77ed5ab-0d66-43c0-8c2d-3326cbe8aae9:/runs/1a3fc5c8-3538-43b7-b9d6-dda4bf2e6d49/tasks/ct:1486450275786:0:sample_1-0_3-4_d77ed5ab-0d66-43c0-8c2d-3326cbe8aae9:/task.info'
I0207 00:51:15.875020 10351 containerizer.cpp:484] Starting container '1a3fc5c8-3538-43b7-b9d6-dda4bf2e6d49' for executor 'ct:1486450275786:0:sample_1-0_3-4_d77ed5ab-0d66-43c0-8c2d-3326cbe8aae9:' of framework '20170206-001647-2583779338-5050-19797-0001'
I0207 00:51:15.875906 10356 slave.cpp:1401] Queuing task 'ct:1486450275786:0:sample_1-0_3-4_d77ed5ab-0d66-43c0-8c2d-3326cbe8aae9:' for executor ct:1486450275786:0:sample_1-0_3-4_d77ed5ab-0d66-43c0-8c2d-3326cbe8aae9: of framework '20170206-001647-2583779338-5050-19797-0001
I0207 00:51:15.876716 10356 slave.cpp:600] Successfully attached file '/opt/leantaas/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/20170206-001647-2583779338-5050-19797-S0/frameworks/20170206-001647-2583779338-5050-19797-0001/executors/ct:1486450275786:0:sample_1-0_3-4_d77ed5ab-0d66-43c0-8c2d-3326cbe8aae9:/runs/1a3fc5c8-3538-43b7-b9d6-dda4bf2e6d49'

I0207 00:52:15.875185 10356 slave.cpp:3605] Terminating executor ct:1486450275786:0:sample_1-0_3-4_d77ed5ab-0d66-43c0-8c2d-3326cbe8aae9: of framework 20170206-001647-2583779338-5050-19797-0001 because it did not register within 1mins
```

Comment: The task is probably segfaulted without exiting properly. What do task logs (you can access them via sandbox in the Mesos UI or locally in the agent's sandbox) say?

Comment: I'm using default mesos containizer, I see in the log the executor terminated becuase of time out./

Comment: Terminating executor ct:1484866005382:0:TXXXXXXX-1-0_3-4_f5f0b884-d17b-45e0-ae45-88b669360349: of framework 20170112-033024-2583779338-5050-595-0000 because it did not register within 1mins

Comment: I didn't see any log files generated, basically the executor terminated and the job stays for ever in STAGING. I checked locally in workdir and I don't see any logs /run/{container_id}

Comment: Can you share the agent log?

Comment: @rukletsov I've added my agent logs. I'm using default "mesos containerzer". Chronos is my framework which schedules the jobs

Comment: I see two separate issues here: (1) your executor does not register and (2) killed executor does not trigger task transition from staging to failed. To debug these issues, more logs are needed: agent, master, executor, all preferably verbose (with GLOG_v=1).